# Create C++ Code from Visio UML diagram

Tags: c++, architecture, reverse-engineering, visio, class-diagram

Visio 2010 Beta can generate static UML diagram from Native C++ project, and it's great. How is it possible to solve reverse problem: given a static UML diagram from Visio, generate header files?

Or, maybe, there are free tools for architecture development and reverse engineering?

**EDIT**
Generally speaking, I don't need diagrams to be strictly UML. They just should be clear enough to look at them and understand classes during designing application, implementing and supporting. But it must have a feature of reverse-engineering and generating code.

I'll try to use offered alternatives in several days and then write a little comparison.

1. **ArgoUML**
   I tried to import my existing code and failed. The reason is that C++ support is pre-alpha. Many constructions of the language are not supported yet. From MessageBox shown while importing:

> The C++ reverse engineering module is
>   pre-alpha stage. Its known limits are:
>
> ```
> * very few C++ constructs are supported, e.g., enums, unions, templates, etc, aren't;
> * no support for non-member variables and functions;
> * no integration with the C++ generator => RTE won't work!;
> * no operator overload support;
> * very immature, certainly this list needs to grow!
> ```

Answer (score 4):

1. Bring up diagram in Visio
2. Bring up Visual Studio, open c++ project.
3. Start typing in code :)

Seriously, Viso is a visual tool and represents it's data in a form best suited to rendering. This lacks information needed to construct a code model from it, unless it were to use some complex vision and edge detection algorithms.

So, I don't think there will be any such tool out there.

Comment: For me it seems that there should be such tools because it is very convenient. And Microsoft has VS to develop and Visio to show diagrams (and Visio has a Toolbox in VS which reverse-engineers code to UML). If I were a Microsoft I'd created a some tool (or feature for Visio/VS) to generate diagrams. By now I know only Sysbase Powerdesigner which can do such things (code<-->UML). And Visio can do with database diagrams. But to C++... :((

Comment: +1 flashnik thanks for the feedback. I'm surprised visio can do that with database diagrams, though.

Comment: I've found that there was Visio 2003 for Enterprise Architects and it was shipped with Team Suite VS. It can generate C++ and .Net code from UML diagram. So the problem can be not in Visio but in modern version of studio. Maybe let's create a feature request for Visio 2010 and VS 2010 while both of them are in beta?

Answer (score 4):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) is a free (and better) alternative with code generation possibility.
Most paid UML tools generate code too.

Answer (score 3):

ArgoUML is a nice, free tool that can generate UML class diagrams then generate source code from the diagram. ArgoUML can output code in several languages, including C++.

You can find it at:
http://argouml.tigris.org

Comment: Tigris.. I love tigris products :)
Thank you, I'll try it and then reply again.

Comment: I also really like the "design critics" they critique the UML that you have written thereby helping you to write better UML. :)

Comment: No, it's not good for C++. I tried to import project and it failed...
Hope, they will develop it and fix problems. Now it's very early product

Comment: I have been able to generate C++ code from UML with ArgoUML. However, it does not yet generate UML from C++ code. I was not worried about that because your original question was "How is it possible to solve reverse problem: given a static UML diagram from Visio, generate header files?". ArgoUML handles that just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems has worked well for me.